# Adding `numpy.linalg.det` as method to `numpy.matrix`

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I wanted to write `M.det()` instead of `numpy.linalg.det(M)`, 
so I did this:

`numpy.matrix.det = numpy.linalg.det`

and it worked.

Is there anything to be said against this proceeding?

---

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.matrix.det = np.linalg.det
M = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
print M.det()
```

correct output: `-2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [monkey patching](http://www.pererikstrandberg.se/blog/index.cgi?page=PythonMonkeyPatch). It may work in this special case, but it makes your program hard to follow since the `det` method only exists in your program and is not documented anywhere. Also, it relies on `np.matrix` implementation details, specifically that it is a pure Python class, and doesn't work for all classes:

```
>>> numpy.ndarray.det = numpy.linalg.det
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I would advise against this; it makes your program harder to read and maintain and there's really no reason not to write `from numpy.linalg import det`, then `det(A)` instead of `A.det()`.

Comment: I think there is another point: `np.linalg.det` takes one argument, which is used as "self" if you make it a method of `np.matrix`. I think it wouldn't work if there where multiple arguments or no argument at all.

Comment: @bmu: it would work with multiple arguments, then the first one would be the instance it is called on and the rest is passed as usual. It wouldn't make sense for a zero-argument function to be an instance method, since it's not called *on* anything.

Comment: you are right but thats what I mean: it is more or less random that it works with this function as it takes an argument. just wanted to mention that, no problem with your answer.